# How to effectively .then chain on client with .catch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, try-catch

I have the following .then example chain in my React Native client code, currently without a .catch because I am looking for advice on how to set it up:

```
await getUserInfo(userId, JSON.stringify(ratingsQueryRatingType), 1)
.then(async userRatingData => {
  await findMatchHistory(userId, '', 3)
  .then(async matchHistoryData => {
```

These functions make calls to my NodeJS server. The NodeJS server then sends back the data.

I am trying to find out how I can effectively send back an error from the server to the client, and have the .catch part in the client handle that (e.g. with Alert.alert(error)).

I tried to throw an error on my server as follows but then on my server I get Unhandled promise rejection. It appears that it does not send the error back to client.

```
// Other code before this part
if (response==='Success') {
    return res.status(200).json({'status': 'success'})
} else {
    throw 'Match record was not confirmed successfully'
}
```

Or is it common practice to send response objects from the server (instead of Errors) and then handling those on the client with some kind of if-statement, such as the following?

```
if (results['status']==='success') {
  // Code
} else if (results['status']==='failure') {
  // Code
}
```

I do read about .then chaining with .catch being an attractive option so it feels like this would not be the correct solution..

Comment: I would recommend *not* mixing async/await with .then like that.

Comment: You cannot just `throw` if there is no middleware on your server that will catch it. At some point, you must send something to the client. Usually that's something like `res.status(200).json({status: 'processing error'})` or `res.status(400).json({status: 'input error'})` or `res.status(500).json({status: 'unexpected internal error'})`. Then, you need to decipher that at the client, where you can reject a promise with the error message.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. @Bergi Ok, the server part is solved then. That leaves just the client part

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Could you elaborate? Maybe it is obvious for you but for me the topic isn't clear yet

Comment: Well for example the first part becomes `const userRatingData = await getUserInfo(...);`. Or you could return the promises from vanilla callbacks rather than having nested async callbacks that each await one thing and return nothing. Right now you have the worst of both worlds. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function.

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly the 'await' in front of the functions names are unnecessary and I can either remove those words or go with your solution to store it in a variable and work with that variable. Thank you. With regard to my question of how to handle (pseudo) errors correctly on the client: how would you advise me to display errors on the client if the server does not give the desired data. You would use if-statements? Like if (userRatingData['response']==='failure)?

Answer (score 1):

I think we should send error-codes to the client instead of sending message although you can do it too. you can check the status code based on the error occurred on the backend -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Also, on client side you can use interceptor and create an error-handler service layer and based on the code you will be sending to the client side you can handle that. you can follow these steps to setup one for your app : https://bilot.group/articles/using-react-router-inside-axios-interceptors/

And, On the backend side if there is an error try logging it to log files on your server.

```
// Other code before this part
if (response==='Success') {
    return res.status(200).json({'status': 'success'})
} else {
    res.status(based on what happened on server).json({'status': 'failure'})
}
```

For .then channing instead you should use async/await. for better understanding how to use them and convert chain to asyn/await. This doc contains the step-by-step guide: https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-refactor-a-promise-chain-to-async-functions/